# TwiML If User hang up

Tags: twilio

I am using the following `TwiMl` code to record a user over the phone:

```
<Response>     
      <Record action="@nextPageUrl" maxLength="15" method="GET" trim="trim-silence" finishOnKey="*" />        
</Response>
```

I would like to do something if the user hang up and not pressed * to end the recording. I am looking for something like `ifHangUp`:

```
<Record ifHangUp="@someUrl" action="@nextPageUrl" ....
```

Does twilio support something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the twiml documentation page: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record you'll see the request sent after in may include the value "hangup" in the "Digits" parameter for the case where the caller hung up the the "action" set. I believe this should provide you a way of detecting a hangup vs a "*".

Basically, for an implementation have a conditional statement on @nextPageUrl examine the the Digits parameter and use a redirect tag to @someUrl if Digit = 'hangup'